# MYSQL Count, LEFT OUTER JOIN with 0 count on a simple case

Tags: mysql, join, count, zero, outer-join

Considering the two following sample tables

**TABLE 1 : 'users'**

```
ID    REGISTER_TIME    FIRSTNAME    LASTNAME    OPERATION_ID

1     1401789877       John         Doe         29
2     1401789879       Jack         Doe         29
3     1401789878       Pete         Doe         29
```

(Note that the register_time column is stored as INT(11))

**TABLE 2 : 'calendar_days'**

```
ID    DAY
1     2011-01-01
...   ....
n     2030-31-12
```

I have the following MySQL query which is working great :

```
SELECT d.day, COUNT(d.day)
FROM calendar_days AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS l ON DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.`register_time`)) = d.day
WHERE l.`operation_id` = 29
GROUP BY d.day;
```

But it doesn't keep the days where count equals zero :

```
day;COUNT(d.day)

2014-05-07;1
2014-05-09;1
2014-05-12;11
2014-05-13;2713
2014-05-14;2631
```

What i want :

```
2014-05-07;1
**2014-05-08;0**
2014-05-09;1
2014-05-12;11
2014-05-13;2713
2014-05-14;2631
```

I feel like i'm close from the truth, I've tried any join possible left outer, right outer, still no empty results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `where` clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join` since you use a condition on the joined table. Try

```
SELECT d.day, COUNT(d.day)
FROM calendar_days AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS l ON DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.`register_time`)) = d.day
                           AND l.`operation_id` = 29
GROUP BY d.day;
```

Comment: Makes perfectly sense, i didn't know it was possible to add multiple conditions on a join. Thank you !